# Slideout tab should stick to leftside of Div on smaler screens no matter what

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm building this SlideOut filter div. The Div is default on the right side of larger screens but when the screen size shrinks the `Sidebar`becomes hidden and the .SlideOutTab appears.

Between  768px and 992px the `.slideOutTab`and the `#facetsSlide` are not behaving as they are supposed to do.

The both divs floats appart.

I've put CSS in media queries for the space between  768px and 992px, but that didn't change what is happening.

here is a [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/b0v2964a/18/)

Can someone help me with this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slideOutTab').on("click", function(){
    $("#facetsSlide").toggleClass('show');
    $('.slideOutTab').toggleClass('showSlideOut');

  } );
});
```

```css
/* Display slideOut */
.content {
  background: gray;
  min-height: 100vh;
  order: 2; }

#facetsSlide {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px; }

#facetsSlide.show {
  transform: inherit;
  display: block;
  background: #fff; }

.showSlideOut {
  right: 300px !important; }

.custom-control.ls-checkbox:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f9f9f9; }

.custom-control.ls-checkbox .material-control-input {
  display: none; }
  .custom-control.ls-checkbox .material-control-input:checked ~ .material-control-indicator {
    border-color: #c2002d;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg) translate(1px, -5px);
    width: 10px;
    border-top: 0px solid #fff;
    border-left: 0px solid #fff; }

.custom-control.ls-checkbox .material-control-indicator {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #bab9b9;
  transition: .3s; }

/* Tab */
.slideOutTab {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
  /*margin-top: -300px;*/
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  /*left: -40px;*/
  right: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 40px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
  border: 1px solid #bab9b9; }

.slideOutTab div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 70px;
  top: 90px;
  color: #c2002d;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  writing-mode: lr-tb; }

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  #facetsSlide {
    display: none;
    transform: translateX(-100%); } }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .slideOutTab {
    display: none; } }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webui-popover/2.1.15/jquery.webui-popover.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container d-flex w-100" id="main">
  <div class="col content ">
 Search results
 </div>
  <!-- // SlideOut -->
  <div class="col-md-3 " id="facetsSlide">

    <article class="card-group-item">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h6 class="title">FilterBlock1:</h6>
      </header>
      <div class="filter-content">
        <div class="card-body">
            <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox" for="Check1">
              <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">15054</span>

              <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input" id="Check1">
                <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="material-control-description">Filter1</span>
            </label>

              <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox" for="Check2">
                <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">2165</span>

                <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input" id="Check2">
                  <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                  <span class="material-control-description">Filter2</span>
              </label>

                <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox" for="Check3">
                  <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">2364</span>

                  <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input" id="Check3">
                    <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="material-control-description">Filter3</span>
                </label>

                  <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox" for="Check4">
                    <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">475</span>

                    <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input" id="Check4">
                      <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                      <span class="material-control-description">Filter4</span>
                  </label>


                    <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox" for="Check5">
                      <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">215</span>

                      <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input" id="Check5">
                        <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                        <span class="material-control-description">Filter5</span>
                    </label>

        </div> <!-- card-body.// -->
      </div>

        <header class="card-header">
          <h6 class="title">FilterBlock2</h6>
        </header>
        <div class="filter-content">
          <div class="card-body">
        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">29</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1819-1828</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">77</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
          <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="material-control-description">1829-1838</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">260</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
          <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="material-control-description">1839-1848</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">1103</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1849-1858</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">1574</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1859-1868</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">2541</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1869-1878</span>
        </label>


        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">4550</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1879-1888</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">10232</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
          <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="material-control-description">1889-1898</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">18155</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
          <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="material-control-description">1899-1908</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">29341</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1909-1918</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">36170</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1919-1928</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">49566</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1929-1938</span>
        </label>



        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">60152</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1939-1948</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">82785</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
          <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="material-control-description">1949-1958</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">111613</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
          <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="material-control-description">1959-1968</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">125677</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1969-1978</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">166842</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1979-1988</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">176976</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1989-1998</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">149340</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">1999-2008</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">110611</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">2009-2018</span>
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control ls-checkbox">
          <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">917</span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="material-control-description">2019</span>
        </label>

  </div> <!-- card-body.// -->

        </div>
      </article> <!-- card-group-item.// -->


</div>

<div class="slideOutTab">
 <div>
   <p>Filter Search</p>
 </div>
</div>

  </div><!-- Content -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1, the two blocks are falling apart or floating away is because of this,

```
/* In grid.scss file */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-md-3 {
    max-width: 25%;
    }
}
```

solution is to override it with your desired width,

```
#facetsSlide {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

Issue 2 and 3, the right side filter block was not appearing because there were no media queries given for it and there is one unnecessary property that i removed,

```
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  #facetsSlide {
    /*transform: translateX(-100%); removed */ } 
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { /* Added query */
   #facetsSlide {
     display: block;
   }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Tan007/syb3rk81/5/) is a fiddle. I hope this is the expected result. If not, comment below.

Comment: Thank you so much it looks like what I was trying to reach.